# An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. c#

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, faultexception

My service was working well, and suddenly It started occurred the following error:

> An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other
>   party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.

I am getting this error at this step of my code:

```
var channel = (WSTrustChannel)trustChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
var token = channel.Issue(rst, out rstr) as GenericXmlSecurityToken;
```

any thought please on what the matter is or how to fix it

Thank you

EDIT:

```
<InnerException><ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.FaultException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>An error occurred when verifying security for the message.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Fault(Exception exception)    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.ProcessReply(Message reply, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState, TimeSpan timeout)    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&amp;amp; msgData, Int32 type)    at System.ServiceModel.Security.IWSTrustContract.Issue(Message message)   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst, RequestSecurityTokenResponse&amp;amp; rstr)    at WebService.RequestToken(String serviceNamespace, WSTrustChannelFactory trustChannelFactory)    at WebService.RequestSecurityToken()    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.LogicalMethodInfo.Invoke(Object target, Object[] values)    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SyncSessionlessHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp;amp; completedSynchronously)    at System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)    at System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)    at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)    at System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(IntPtr ecb, Int32 iWRType) </StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.FaultException: An error occurred when verifying security for the message.</ExceptionString></InnerException>
```

Comment: So did you see the inner `FaultException` for the fault code and detail, as the exception message said? What was it?

Comment: I only can see this:  **An error occurred when verifying security for the message.**

Comment: Well there should certainly be more to it than that - there should be the *type* of the `FaultException`, for example... and it might have a further inner exception.

Comment: I added the whole InnerException in my post above here is the ExcpetionType

**_<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.FaultException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>_**